# Reason for overlapping instances error when not quantifying method existentially

Tags: haskell, type-families, overlapping-instances

Given the following code, removing `forall a r` from the type of `go` fails with "Overlapping instances for Typeable (D r)". I wonder why?

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module M where

import Data.Typeable (Proxy, Typeable, cast)

class C r where
    data D r :: *

deriving instance Typeable D

data A = forall r . A (D r)

go :: forall r a . (Typeable a, Typeable (D r)) => a -> Proxy r -> A
go a _ = case cast a of
  Just (b :: D r) -> A b
  Nothing -> error "fail to cast"
```

The error also says "The choice depends on the instantiation of `r`" - but isn't that pinned by the supplied `Proxy r`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how scoped type variables work in Haskell. Note that you are re-using `r` here:

```
go :: forall r a . (Typeable a, Typeable (D r)) => a -> Proxy r -> A
go a _ = case cast a of
  Just (b :: D r) -> A b  -- this r is the same as the r above
```

Without the explicit `forall`, type variables are interpreted to be local to the signature. That is, your code is read as:

```
go :: (Typeable a1, Typeable (D r1)) => a1 -> Proxy r1 -> A  -- renaming local variables
go a _ = case cast a of
  Just (b :: D r) -> A b   -- r bears no relation to r1
```

Hence the type error.

(It *is* confusing to get an `Overlapping instances` error, though.)

Comment: Thank you! It would indeed be nice to emit a warning "you use a type variable of the same name, did you intend to add forall?".

Comment: @ron I strongly concur. I'd even go as far as changing the Haskell definition so that scoped type variables are enabled by default, with or without forall. This would break compatibility, but I really wonder how much this will break (my uninformed guess is very little).